# My font-size changes depending on the number of items

Tags: html, css, font-size

I create a mobile part for my site (which doesn't use the @media because it's another part of the site, and I prefer to do a different view), except that my font-size screws up, but a lot.

For example, when you have to scroll through the page, the font-size of certain items becomes either too big or too small, and I don't know where that comes from?

Like what:

1/2 Items:

[image: IMAGE 1]

2 or more items:

[image: IMAGE 2]

My code:

```css
.page-mnu
{
  padding: 15.2vh 1.2vh;
  animation-name: arrivedroite;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.8s;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
}

.box-show {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 2.8rem 0;
}

.box-ind {
  border: 0.2rem solid black;
  margin: 1.3rem 0;
}

.tt-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5.2vh;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
}

.cnt-box {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-mnu">
  <b>Bonjour NOM - PRENOM</b>
  <div class="box-show">
    <div class="box-ind" style="border-color: #22248EFF;">
      <div class="tt-box" style="background: #22248EFF;">Infos de l'établissement</div>
      <div class="cnt-box"><i>Aucune information pour le moment</i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-ind" style="border-color: #22248EFF;">
      <div class="tt-box" style="background: #22248EFF;">Infos de l'établissement</div>
      <div class="cnt-box"><i>Aucune information pour le moment</i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-ind" style="border-color: #22248EFF;">
      <div class="tt-box" style="background: #22248EFF;">Infos de l'établissement</div>
      <div class="cnt-box"><i>Aucune information pour le moment</i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-ind" style="border-color: #22248EFF;">
      <div class="tt-box" style="background: #22248EFF;">Infos de l'établissement</div>
      <div class="cnt-box"><i>Aucune information pour le moment</i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-ind" style="border-color: #22248EFF;">
      <div class="tt-box" style="background: #22248EFF;">Infos de l'établissement</div>
      <div class="cnt-box"><i>Aucune information pour le moment</i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-ind" style="border-color: #22248EFF;">
      <div class="tt-box" style="background: #22248EFF;">Infos de l'établissement</div>
      <div class="cnt-box"><i>Aucune information pour le moment</i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS is missing a selector for the first ruleset. I can't seem to reproduce the problem, so it probably comes from other CSS on the page.

Comment: Your font-size seems to be defined in rem, which depend on font-size of the root element. If the root element have different font-size on different pages, it will change accordingly the font-size defined with rem

Comment: @SeeoX I don't think I have a base font-size, so if I understand correctly the rem inherits from the root element? it must be a px or can it be in rem / em? (My css : https://mobile.schoolmore.cf/css/style_index.css )

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had forgotten the meta viewport, thank you anyway!